# How can I hide name of file uploaded using <p:fileUpload/>

Tags: file-upload, primefaces

Hello after upload an image using `p:fileUpload`, it shows the name of the file like this [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zm8hx.png) presents.

My issue is how can I hide the name `BillGates.JPG` after clicking on `Choose Background`.
--> So, I want to have after clicking on `Choose Background` and before clicking on `Register` this [NewScreenchot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46sIC.png) instead of the first one.
Below is the `file upload component` to choose an image:

```html
<p:fileUpload id="bck" 
       value="#{connectedUserBean.file}" 
       allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/"
       label="Choose Background"
       mode="simple" 
       skinSimple="true"
       auto="true"/>
```

The `button` to save it is:

```html
<p:commandButton value="Register" 
   update="ee" ajax="false"
        style="width: 100px;height: 30px;font-size: 13px;background-color: #ff66d9;" 
        actionListener="#{connectedUserBean.upload}"/>
```

Have you please any idea about solving this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: "Below is the button:"  there is only p:fileupload tag visible and no button tag.(p:commandButton)

Comment: Hello Sir @ArgaPK, Thanks for your reply and sorry I made change on my question, but What I want is to hide the name of the file `after` clicking on the button `'Choose Background` and `before` clicking on the button `Register`. Could you please take a look. Thanks a lot

Comment: "Choose Background" is a file upload component and not a button

Comment: you said in your question you want to hide the file name after clicking "Choose Photo" button?

Comment: Yes Sir I want to hide the file name after clicking on  "Choose Photo" file upload component. In other word, I want select an image without displaying its name.

Comment: From your question "Choose Backgroud" is the label name of p:fileupload and from the screenshot "Choose Photo" is the button to hide the name of the file, and then again from your question there is another button "register" to save it. Am I right??

Comment: Really sorry Sir @ArgaPK about that, I corrected my question, I want to hide the image name after clicking on `Choose Background` . In other word, I don't want to show the name of the background `BilGates.JPG` after choose it and before clicking on `Register button`.

Comment: "Choose Background" is not a simply button, it is a file select button.; you select a file from it.

Comment: Yes Sir @ArgaPK, I select an image called `BilGates.JPG`, but after selecting this image I don't want to display the name  `BilGates.JPG`, I'd like to hide this name after selecting the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this to your css file:

```
.ui-fileupload-filename {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir @sunofkyuss for your reply. It works as well.